# getting a JS eventListener when scrolled max right or left

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slideshow with arrows to scroll the slide show.

I would like to make the arrow disappear when I reach the end of the scrolling (right or left).

I know how to use the hide function to hide the arrow with Javascript, however I don't know how to get the correct event to run this function.

Does anyone knows what event I could use to check when I reached the maximum scroll right or left?

```
<div class="slideshow">
   <div class="displayImage">
      <img id="featured" src="{{ game.imageMain }}">
   </div>
   <div class="row slide-wrapper">
       <div class="arrow" id="prev"></div>
       <div id="slider">
           <img class="thumbnail thumbnail-active" src="{{ game.imageMain }}">

           {% for image in game.images%}
               <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ image.url }} alt="{{ image.caption }}"">
           {% endfor %}
                                        
       </div>
       <div class="arrow" id="next"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS :

```
let thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')
let activeimages = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail-active')

for (var i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
    thumbnails[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        
        if (activeimages.length > 0) {
        activeimages[0].classList.remove('thumbnail-active')
        }
        this.classList.add('thumbnail-active')
        document.getElementById('featured').src = this.src
    })
}
let prev = document.getElementById('prev')
let next = document.getElementById('next')


prev.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft -= 180
})
next.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft += 180
})
```

Regards

Comment: I try to come back again to see if anyone can help please